# CSS Multi Column Minimal Width

Tags: css

I got a `div` which uses the multi-column feature of `css`. The content of the `div` is a text with an arbitrary length.

I use the following stylesheet for the `div`:

```
*-column-count: auto;
*-column-gap:   40px;
*-column-width: 250px;
/* (* is -webkit,-moz,...) */
```

How can I set that this `div` has the `width` of all columns together.

For example, if I got a short text, only one column is used. Then the `width` should be `250px`

If the text is longer, two columns are used. Then the `width` should be `540px` (2 columns and the gap)

Here is the JFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/arnzel/rcegmozy/

Comment: I'd be glad to help, but two things first: **1)** use 4 spaces of indentation before each line of your included CSS code (clicking on code formatting will do this automatically for you), so that it is easier and prettier to read, **2)** prepare a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), so we can see what you have in action. [ask]

Comment: @JánosWeisz why not a [jsBin](http://jsbin.com) (which is BTW a far better online tool)? I mean... c'mon, He has the > **Include Snippet** button, and if enough - no *fiddle* should be provided.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan That's entirely up to preference in my opinion. But right, I should have used a collaborative naming for an online tool of choice.